# AJAX send public static function

Tags: php, html, ajax

I want to insert a `like` into the database, but I want this on multiple pages. I crated a page where I insert the `likes` and I included this page on all the other pages.
It works, but now every time I `like`, the page is reloading. I thought I could fix this with AJAX, but I couldn't find a solution.

Index.php:

```
include_once('Post.php');

if(isset($_GET['postId'])) {
    Post::likePost($_GET['postId'], $userId);
}

//Here sql to select postText, postId...
//Here echo the post

<form action="index.php?postId='.$postId.'" method="post">   
    <input type="submit" name="like" value="Like">
    <input type="submit" name="unlike" value="Unlike">
</form>
```

Post.php:

```
class Post {
    public static function likePost($postId, $likerId) {
        //select database and check if user already liked post. If yes: -1 like if no: +1 like
    }
}
```

Does anyone know if I can use AJAX to send the `Post::likePost($_GET['postId'], $userId);` so I can `like` a post without refreshing?

Comment: Not like this. You need to use `ajax` and update number of likes on success. Or use some reactive frontend frameworks like VueJS or React.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I do that?

Comment: You can read any `likes` tutorial, really :)

Comment: there is a syntax error as well `if(isset($_GET['postId'] { ` it should be `if(isset($_GET['postId'])) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can try it. the code is well commented

```
<html><head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script 
  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"> 
  type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>


<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".like, .unlike").click(function(){ 

var postId= 1;
//var post1 = $('#postId').val();
 var id_likeunlike = this.id;   // Getting Button id for like or unlike
var userId= 101;

var datasend = "postId="+ postId + "&id_likeunlike=" + id_likeunlike + "&userId=" + userId;

// display a loading image when sending ajax request
$('#loader').fadeIn(400).html('<br><span class="well"><img src="loader.gif" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;Please Wait, Your Data is being Submitted</span>');

        $.ajax({

            type:'POST',
            url:'post.php',
            data:datasend,
                        crossDomain: true,
            cache:false,
            success:function(msg){
$('#loader').hide();
            alert('success');   

                $('#listpost').fadeIn('slow').prepend(msg);

            }


        });


});

});




</script>
  </head>
    <body>
<div id="loader"> </div>
    <div id="listpost"> </div>


    <input type="submit" id="like" class="like" name="like" value="Like">
    <input type="submit" id="unlike" class="unlike"  name="unlike" value="Unlike">

</body>
```

**post.php**

```
<?php

$postId = intval($_POST['postId']); 
$id_likeunlike = strip_tags($_POST['id_likeunlike']); 
$userId = strip_tags($_POST['userId']); 


if($id_likeunlike=='like'){
echo "like success";
}
elseif($id_likeunlike=='unlike'){
echo "unlike success";
}

else{
echo "Error occured";
}


?>
```